# Get value after some specific character in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I want to extract the `value` from a `string` the `value` will place at the right after my specific character in this case my specific character is `-` and will place at the right.

The `string` will look like this:

```
TEST-QWE-1
TEST/QWE-22
TEST@QWE-3
TEST-QWE-ASD-4
```

And from that `string` I want to extract

```
1
22
3
4
```

How I do that in C#? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `IndexOf`. Here some examples that may help you getting started: https://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

Comment: Should the result be a string, an int, a double? Is the number always at the end?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd the result will always be number at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf("-") + 1)
```

---

Or use `LastIndexOf` in case there are other dashes before the last part:

```
mystring.Substring(mystring.LastIndexOf("-") + 1)
```

---

> `Substring`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2
>
> `LastIndexOf`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to learn about Regex for string processing.
In your case a simple Regex pattern like `[0-9]+$` would match your numbers.

Since you stated that the number is always to the right of your string you could also use `string.Split('-').Last()`. Use this if you value code readability and maintainability.

If you're concerned about performance and memory usage, especially for very long strings, then `Substring()` and `LastIndexOf()` may be a more efficient option.

In most cases, the performance difference is negligible, and you can choose the one that makes your code more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_) to get the last occurrence of '-'

```
var p = str.LastIndexOf('-');
return p >= 0 && (p + 1 < str.Length) ? str.Substring(p + 1) : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.LastIndexOf() and string.Substring() to do that. And take care when the special character not occurred in your input.

```
string[] inputs = new string[]{ 
    "TEST-QWE-1", 
    "TEST/QWE-22",
    "TEST@QWE-3", 
    "TEST-QWE-ASD-4", 
    "TEST-QWE-ASD-4", 
    "TEST",
    "TEST-"
};
foreach(string input in inputs){
    int lastIdx = input.LastIndexOf("-");
    string output = lastIdx > -1 ? input.Substring(lastIdx + 1) : "";
    Console.WriteLine(input + " => " + output);
}
/* console outputs:
TEST-QWE-1 => 1
TEST/QWE-22 => 22
TEST@QWE-3 => 3
TEST-QWE-ASD-4 => 4
TEST-QWE-ASD-4 => 4
TEST =>
TEST- =>
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I will post another regex to capture what you want: `-([^-]+)$`

It's different from already posted, since it will capture everything except hyphen (with `[^-]+`) between hyphen (`-`) and end of a string (`$` means end of a string).

The desired result will be stored in first cupturing group.

Code snippet:

```
var s = "TEST-QWE-1";
var match = Regex.Match(s, "-([^-]+)$");
if (match.Success)
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qL9ltm/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex`, and this is the string you will need.
`[^-]+$`

Simply loop over each string you have.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([^-]+$)");

regex.Matches(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Regex like `(-\d+$)`

You can as well use `Split()` and get the last element

```
"TEST-QWE-ASD-4".Split('-').Last();
```

Comment: The OP is asking about C#, which doesn't use `/` delimiters for its regex

Comment: @HansKeﬆing need not be ... that's just the regular expression. edited to remove confusion

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is use the LastIndexOf method like this :

```
string input = "TEST-QWE-1";
var lastIndex = input.LastIndexOf("-");
var id = input.Substring(lastIndex + 1); // this is so you don't get the minus as well if you don't want it.
```

so, first we get the last index of the character we care about.
second, we perform a substring using this index to get the result we want